# Applying VBA for a particular cell to a selection/column automatically

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and require some assistance. I have found VBA that will look at the value of the active cell and insert a number of rows equal to the value in the cell.

The problem I have is that this only works for the active cell, I have a column for which I would like this process to be automated for. Would anyone know what I should change in the code below?

```
Sub InsertSome()
Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, m As Long
n = ActiveCell.Value
m = ActiveCell.Row
For i = 1 To n
    Rows(m * i + 1).Insert
Next i
End Sub
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'a column for which I would like this process to be automated'? You want columns inserted when something happens?

Comment: I think both chaps below have got your question while I didn't, but do you really want lots of rows inserted every time you select a cell in a column? That might get irritating.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Events`. Insert this code in the module of the sheet where you want this working. It will run every time you select a cell in column C.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing And Target.Value <> "" Then '<-Change "C:C" to your column
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, m As Long
    n = Target.Value
    m = Target.Row
    For i = 1 To n
        Rows(m * i + 1).Insert
    Next i
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the `Worksheet` events, such as `Worksheet_SelectionChange` or `Worksheet_Change` events.

Also, you don't need to have so many variables, you can use the properties of `Target` object (equivalent to `ActiveCell`). **Also**, you can add multiple rows at once (there's no need to have a `For` loop).

***Code***

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

' modify column "A" to your desired column
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
    ' make sure the value is numeric, positive, and you select a single cell
    If Target.Value > 0 And Trim(Target.Value) <> "" And IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        ' no need for a loop to add 1 row at a time,
        ' just use the line below to add the number of rows in the Target (acitveCell) at once
        Range(Cells(Target.Row + 1, 1), Cells(Target.Row + Target.Value, 1)).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
End If

End Sub
```